# Model "namespacing" for wpf StyleSelector?

Tags: wpf, xaml, avalondock

I am learning how to use avalonDock by debugging its test sample apps. Something I have not been able to explain at this stage is the presence of the ***"Model"*** Keyword in some xaml binding.

Mainly in the style selector, if you remove it, the binding does not work anymore:

```
        <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <local:PanesStyleSelector>
                <local:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutAnchorableItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </local:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
                <local:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Model.FilePath}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
                    </Style>
                </local:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
            </local:PanesStyleSelector>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
```

1. [MainWindow.xaml](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp/MainWindow.xaml)
2. [PaneStyleSelector](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp/PanesStyleSelector.cs)

Why ? I have not been able to figure out any "Model" Field or property. And it seems to work without it for other examples:

[Microsoft Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about XAML is that there always seems to be a way to do things a number of ways.  This, of course, makes it difficult to get ahead of the learning curve sometimes too.  In short, whenever you see `{Binding _______}` think `DataContext`.

Also, know that object navigation in XAML is similar to IntelliSense when typing in a normal `.cs` file.  Meaning, if you have:

```
public class A { public B b = new B(); }
public class B { public string C; }
```

then you can get to `A`'s `B`'s `C` by doing `string s = new A().B.C`.

What I'm getting at is, in XAML, these three are the same:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutAnchorableItem}">
    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Title, Path=Model}"/>
    ...

<local:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutAnchorableItem}">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Model}" />
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
        ...

<!-- What you currently have -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutAnchorableItem}">
    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
    ...
```

So really, `Model` is a property the control is going to look for in it's `DataContext`, and it will bind to the Title property belonging to `Model`.

Now the question is, how do you figure out if this is correct?  Simple.  Navigate through the `DataContext`.  There is a number of ways you can do this, rather you debug, or you use `F12`; but here is a quick way to figure it out.

We know the target type is LayoutAnchorableItem: `TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutAnchorableItem}"`, so we look at its [source code](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Controls/LayoutAnchorableItem.cs) and look for the Model property.  After looking, you don't see it, but you also notice that `LayoutAnchorableItem` inherits from `LayoutItem`, which is also our second target type coincidentally.  So we look at `LayoutItem` [source code](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Controls/LayoutItem.cs).  As you know it, there is a `public object Model` property. With that being said, we can make the assumption that through a chain of events, we can figure that our `Model` property ends up getting set to an instance of `FileViewModel` or `ToolViewModel`, and both inherit from `PaneViewModel`.

With that being said, we know that the `DataContext` of each Pane in the `DockingManager` is either a `LayoutAnchorableItem` or `LayoutItem`, whose `Model` is eventually set to an instance of `FileViewModel` or 
`toolViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems so simple now. I am learning WPF, this kind of answer helps a lot.